# .NET http response add some params in IHttpHandler

Tags: .net, web-services

I have service in .NET HttpHandler  which servicing like proxy,
 every request when client send to server at first come in my service after that i lead this request and send to server. i have a question how i can add some params when server return response to client ? e.g.

`Client ---- >  MyService --- >  Server`  when client send request to server.

`Server ----> MyService ----> Client`    when server send response to client.

when Server send response can i add some params in query string ? and if i can how ?

i can catch request

```
if (context.Request.Path.EndsWith("/checkPayment")) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add data that way:

```
Response.Write("Key"+ ":" + "Value");
```

Comment: I have question, request can catch like above(context.Request.Path.EndsWith("/checkPayment")) and response how i can catch ?

Comment: It depends on how do you send Request on server. Basically if you use $.Ajax you can handle response in "success" parameter like this : success: function (response, a, b) {
        alert(response);
    }  
Otherwise please provide more code on "Server ----> MyService ----> Client "